# How to call a method inside a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, anonymous-function

I'm just learning about how to best organize my javascript code, and I had a question regarding this small piece of code I wrote:

```
var reportsControllerIndex = {
    plotMapPoints: function(data) {
        //plots points
    },

    drawMap: function() {
        $.getJSON('/reports.json', function(data) {
            reportsControllerIndex.plotMapPoints(data);         
        });
    },

    run: function() {
        reportsControllerIndex.drawMap();
    }
};
```

The question is regarding calling another function of reportsControllerIndex from within the reportsControllerIndex object.  I had first tried the following piece of code for the run function:

```
run: function() {
    this.drawMap();
}
```

which worked perfectly.  However, I then quickly found doing this for the drawMap function:

```
drawMap: function() {
    $.getJSON('/reports.json', function(data) {
        this.plotMapPoints(data);         
    });
}
```

does not work, since "this" would now refer to the callback function of the getJSON call.

My solution was to just place reportsControllerIndex in front of all of the methods I want to call, but I was curious:  is there a more relative way for calling functions within an overall object like this (much like you'd do with a class in a standard OO language)?  Or am I forced to do it as I am currently, just calling the methods through the name of the object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to store the `this` binding in a variable.

```
drawMap: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.getJSON('/reports.json', function(data) {
        _this.plotMapPoints(data);         
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!  Would you say that overall this practice is used in more javascript code than Josiah's suggestion below?  I like the idea of using "self" better just for my own OO mindset, but I'd rather follow standard practices in the JS world where I can.

Comment: @japancheese - I don't believe there is a convention so you should use what you like. Just remember to keep the name reasonable.

Answer (score 8):

Late answer, but jQuery has a method [called `jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) that is made for this purpose. You pass it the function along with the value of `this` you want to retain, and it will return a function that ensures `this` is correct.

This way you don't need to define a variable.

```
drawMap: function() {
    $.getJSON('/reports.json', $.proxy(function(data) {
        this.plotMapPoints(data);         
    }, this));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a variable reference to `this` outside the `getJSON` function. `getJSON` sets the context of the callback within jquery.

**Like this:**

```
var self = this;
$.getJSON('/reports.json', function(data) {
    self.plotMapPoints(data);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plotMapPoints: function(data) {
    //plots points
}.bind(this)
```

when defining your function you can just add .bind(this) to set the correct context for that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it likes this:

```
var reportsControllerIndex = new function () {

    var self = this;

    self.plotMapPoints = function (data) {
        //plots points
    },

    self.drawMap = function () {
        $.getJSON('/reports.json', function (data) {
            self.plotMapPoints(data);         
        });
    },

    self.run = function () {
        self.drawMap();
    }
};
```

This class will works as same as you did, and you can still call the class method by:

```
reportsControllerIndex.run()
```

In this paradigm, I defined `self` pointing to the class itself, so that you can call `self` wherever you want in the class.

---

Farther, this paradigm can solve the `this` problem in the function that you bring as callback to another funciton:

```
plotMapPoints: function(data) {
    console.log(this);
    // Need a this referring to the class itself
    // It's inconvenient to bring this as parameter
},
```