# javascript object, self reference problem

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I just started using oop in javascript and I ran across some problems trying to acces a method from inside another method.

here's the code I had:

```
var Game = {
initialize: function () {
    if (canvas.isSupported()) {
        sprites[0] = new Player();

        this.update();
    }
},

update: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        sprites[i].update();
    }

    this.draw();
},

draw: function() {
    this.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        sprites[i].draw();
    }

    setTimeout(this.update, 10);
},

clear: function() {
    canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.element.width, canvas.element.height);
}
```

}

but calling the Game.update() gives an error that the draw method isn't defined.
I couldn't find a real solution for this.
eventually I found this [How to call a method inside a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393351/how-to-call-a-method-inside-a-javascript-object)
where the answer seems to be that I need to safe the this reference like:
`var _this = this;`
but I couldn't get that to work in literal notation, so I changed the code to object constructor (I guess that's how it's called) and added the variable.

I then changed

```
this.draw();
```

to

```
_this.draw();
```

and it worked.

though the

```
this.clear();
```

and the this.update() are still the same, they never seemed to give errors in the first place.

Can anyone explain why this is? and maybe point me to a better solution?
thanks in advance.

**update**

Here's what it should be:

```
var Game = function () {
var _this = this;

this.initialize = function () {
    if (canvas.isSupported()) {
        sprites[0] = new Player();

        this.update();
    }
}

this.update = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        sprites[i].update();
    }

    this.draw();
}

this.draw = function () {
    this.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        sprites[i].draw();
    }


    setTimeout(function () { _this.update(); }, 10);
}

this.clear = function () {
    canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.element.width, canvas.element.height);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show the complete code that worked?

Comment: +1 for being awesome and posting your update.  This post finally concreted the differences in alternate namespacing methods.  You made me a better coder today. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you do this:

```
setTimeout(this.update, 10);
```

that *does* correctly pass the reference to your "update" function to the system, but when the browser actually calls the function later, it will have no idea what `this` is supposed to be.  What you can do instead is the following:

```
var me = this;
setTimeout(function() { me.update(); }, 10);
```

That will ensure that when "update" is called, it will be called with `this` set correctly as a reference to your object.

Unlike some other languages, the fact that a function is defined initially as a property of an object does not intrinsically bind the function to that object.  In the same way that if you had an object with a propertly that's a simple number:

```
   maxLength: 25,
```

well the value "25" won't have anything in particular to do with the object; it's just a value. In JavaScript, functions are just values too. Thus it's incumbent upon the programmer to make sure that `this` will be set to something appropriate whenever a function is called in some "special" way.

Comment: Umm, sorry about that. I can't recall down voting you. It must have been a misplaced click.

Comment: It may not have been you, @RoToRa -- it will probably remain a mystery :-)

Comment: Well my down vote arrow was orange, so it was probably me. I just don't remember not liking your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you use an object literal instead of an instantiated object

Try to do it this way instead:

```
var Game = function() {
  this.initialize = function () {
    if (canvas.isSupported()) {
      sprites[0] = new Player();
      this.update();
    }
  };
  this.update = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        sprites[i].update();
    }

    this.draw();
  };

  this.draw = function() {
    this.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        sprites[i].draw();
    }

    setTimeout(this.update, 10);
  };

  this.clear = function() {
    canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.element.width, canvas.element.height);
  };
}
```

now use:

```
 var myGame = new Game();
```

Comment: A really good reference for `this`: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Comment: @Pointy: true, the setTimeout is bound to fail, but seems like you are covering that :)

Comment: I agree that it's probably better to go ahead and do it with a constructor like that.